# Use Raphael JavaScript library in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, typescript

Is it possible to use JavaScript libraries in TypeScript?

For example I want to use [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) in TypeScript and added the JS files in my `/scripts folder` and added them to `_references.js`.

But when I want to declare in my TS file:

```
var r = Raphael(10,50,640,480);
```

Intellisense always says:

> `Raphael does not exist in the current scope.`

and the TS file does not compile.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This line is an ambient declaration:

```
declare var Raphael: any;
```

While it works, you get no real typing.

The project [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) already has definitions for Raphael.

Download the [raphael.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/raphael/raphael.d.ts) file.

And use it like this:

```
/// <reference path="../Definitions/raphael.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I support the previous answer, declare Raphael as var with type any and it will work. But if you seriously like to take benefit of type script, then create declaration file for Raphael js. So, that will provide intellisense whenever you use Raphael js. Here is [link](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fe3bc0bfce1f#samples/jquery/jquery.d.ts) for Jquery declaration file which is available in the samples provided by typescript site. Just have a look it will help. Please let me know if any further details required.

Comment: is there a tool to generate a declaration file automatically?

Comment: command line compiler is doing that, but i guess it is for typescript to typescript declaration file, not from javascript to declaration file. You can still try copy pasting from js to ts and try to generate declaration but i am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

As previously, noted, you can just declare Raphael as a var of "any" type, but if you want IntelliSense and compile-time checking, you'll need a declaration file. I've gone ahead and taken an initial stab at this here: https://bitbucket.org/keesey/raphaelts